# Print only first three numbers from string

Tags: bash, sed, cut, substr

I'm trying to print out the memory total in GB but print only the first three digits. I've tried using cut and sed without luck.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo MemoryTotal $(( $(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{ print $2 }') / 1024 ))
```

Yields:

> MemoryTotal 257669GB

But I'd like this to print out:

> MemoryTotal 257GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `free -g`:

```
free -g | awk 'NR==2{print $2}'
```

Comment: that works, thanks! I'll mark this as resolved as soon as it allows me. Love simple solutions!

Answer (score 2):

Since `/proc/meminfo` outputs memory size in KB and you want the output in GB, what you should do instead is to divide the number in KB by 1024 * 1024.

```
echo MemoryTotal $(( $(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $2 }') / 1024 / 1024))GB
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` + `numfmt` tools:

```
sed '1 s/ \(.\)B$/\U\1/;q' /proc/meminfo | numfmt --field 2 --from=auto --to=iec
```

Sample output (from my current OS):

```
MemTotal:            2.2G
```